# Print report only for selected partner

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

There is Partner Ledger report but it prints only for all partners. so i added partner id in the wizard and in wizards view.
Now i need a method that would print report only for selected partners. I hope you guys can give me food for thoughts. maybe some pseudo code how should've i implement it.

```
class AccountPartnerLedger(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = "account.report.partner.ledger"

    partner_ids = fields.Many2many(
        'res.partner', string='Choose partners')
```

i trying to filter by domain method that calls report

```
class ReportPartnerLedger(models.AbstractModel):
    _inherit = 'report.account_extra_reports.report_partnerledger'


    @api.multi
    def render_html(self, data):
        domain = [
                ('partner_ids', '==', 'partner_ids'),
            ]
        return super(ReportPartnerLedger, self).render_html(data=data)
```

Comment: Nobody will write code for you here. You should share your attempts with us and if we can help we will help you with errors or mistakes.

Comment: as i said before i didn't want a code, i wanted some pointers

Comment: ok here is the hint: source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general if you want to filter in partner ledger then you need to override one method from where all the partners are set.

For that you can refer

> **account => report => report_partner_ledger.py**

In that file there is one method

```
def set_context(self, objects, data, ids, report_type=None):
```

You need to override it and need to update one line which will fetch all the partners instead of this you need to pass your field's value here.

```
    self.cr.execute(
            "SELECT DISTINCT l.partner_id " \
            "FROM account_move_line AS l, account_account AS account, " \
            " account_move AS am " \
            "WHERE l.partner_id IS NOT NULL " \
                "AND l.account_id = account.id " \
                "AND am.id = l.move_id " \
                "AND am.state IN %s"
                "AND " + self.query +" " \
                "AND l.account_id IN %s " \
                " " + PARTNER_REQUEST + " " \
                "AND account.active " + reconcile + " ", params)
    self.partner_ids = [res['partner_id'] for res in self.cr.dictfetchall()]
```

This way odoo fetch all the partners for partner ledger report, so just comment out those lines and replace your code.

> For that you must need to inherit the wizard because in that
>   partner_ids field is there in that you need to replace that value.